# In python, if a module calls upon another module's functions, is it possible for the function to access the first module's filepath?

Tags: python, module, filepath

Without passing it as a parameter...

Ex. In test1.py:

```
def function():
    print (?????)
```

and in test2.py

```
import test1

test1.function()
```

Is it possible to write ????? so running test2.py prints out 'test2.py' or the full filepath? **__*file*__** would print out 'test1.py'.

Comment: What's wrong with passing the file path as an argument?

Comment: It feels less graceful, and also allows the writer of test2.py to input something silly (like another filename) into that parameter.

Comment: How the heck `sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename` is more graceful than passing a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`sys._getframe()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```
% cat test1.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def function():
    print 'Called from within:', sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename
```

`test2.py` looks much like yours but with the the `import` fixed:

```
% cat test2.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import test1

test1.function()
```

Test run...

```
% ./test2.py 
Called from within: ./test2.py
```

**N.B:**

> CPython implementation detail: This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the caller's frame first.

```
def fish():
    print sys._getframe(-1).f_code.co_filename
```

Comment: print sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename 

works. Is that what you meant? -1 still prints out test1.py

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need is:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[0]
```

It gives:

```
$ python abc.py 
abc.py
```

Comment: Is it possible for the first argument not to be the filename though?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

test1.py:

```
import inspect
def function():
  print "Test1 Function"
  f = inspect.currentframe()
  try:
    if f is not None and f.f_back is not None:
      info = inspect.getframeinfo(f.f_back)
      print "Called by: %s" % (info[0],)
  finally:
    del f
```

test2.py:

```
import test1
test1.function()
```

```
$ python test2.py
Test1 Function
Called by: test2.py
```

Comment: There's a warning with `inspect.currentframe`: that it is dependent on the python implementation and works with CPython.