# How to know who is importing me in python?

Tags: python, import

How can I find out what file is importing a particular file in python?

Consider the following example:

```
#a.py
import cmn
....

#b.py
import cmn
...

#cmn.py
#Here, I want to know which file (a.py or b.py)
#is importing this one.
#Is it possible to do this?
...
```

All the files `a.py`, `b.py` and `cmn.py` are in the same directory.

Why do I want to do this? 
In C/C++, they have include feature. What i want to do can illuminate by the C/C++ code.

```
//a.cpp
....
#define SOME_STUFF   ....
#include "cmn.h"

//b.cpp
...
#define SOME_STUFF   ....

#include "cmn.h"

//cmn.h
//Here, I'll define some functions/classes that will use the symbol define
//in the a.cpp or b.cpp
...
....code refer to the SOME_STUFF.....
```

In C/C++, we can use this method to reuse sourecode.

Now return to my python code.
When a.py import cmn.py, i hope to run cmn.py and the cmn.py will refer to the symbol defined in the a.py.
When b.py import cmn.py, i hope to run cmn.py and the cmn.py will refer to the symbol defined in the b.py.

Comment: Libraries shouldn't depend on who imports them, so it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan is right. It *can* be done, though, as I demonstrate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025538/in-python-if-a-module-calls-upon-another-modules-functions-is-it-possible-for/7025963#7025963 . However... what is the *real* problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is an alternative way to achieve it without coupling your files like this.

Comment: @Yuncy: Do you want *all imports* of `cmn.py` to run some code in `cmn.py`?  I'm asking this question because the normal way of operation is that Python only imports modules *once*, so `cmn.py` normally only gets one chance of knowing who does `import cmn`.  Tavis Rudd's answer might be the solution, if you want to catch *every* `import cmn`.

Comment: @EOL  You're right. I want to do this. I have improved my question according to the feedback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *namedtuple* code in the *collections* module has an example of how (and when) to do this:

```
#cmn.py
import sys
print 'I am being imported by', sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('__name__')
```

One limitation of this approach is that the outermost module is always named `__main__`.  If that is the case, the name of the outermost module can be determined from `sys.argv[0]`.

A second limitation is that if the code using sys._getframe is in the module scope it is only executed on the first import of cmn.py.  You'd need to call a function of some sort after imports if you want to monitor all imports of the module.

Comment: Note the print statement is only executed on the very first import of the module.  If you want to catch every import, you need to either call a function from cmn.py after each import or use an import hook.

Comment: How would one implement something similar for py3?

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a kind of bizarre thing to do.  You haven't explained *why* you want to know what is importing your module, so I can't actually help you solve your problem.  You also haven't explained how or when you want to know the importing module.

```
def who_imports(studied_module):
    for loaded_module in sys.modules.values():
        for module_attribute in dir(loaded_module):
            if getattr(loaded_module, module_attribute) is studied_module:
                yield loaded_module
```

This will give you an iterator over all the modules which use your module as a top-level object.  It won't find modules that do `from cmn import *`, and the list will change over time.

```
>>> import os
>>> for m in who_imports(os):
...     print m.__name__
... 
site
__main__
posixpath
genericpath
posixpath
linecache
```

Comment: It also looks like it wouldn't handle 'import foo as bar'.

Comment: @TavisRudd: it actually does handle `import foo as bar`: `who_imports(foo)` will return the module that did the import.  This is because the test is made on `module` objects (via `is module`), and not on module names.  Note that the reported module names are the original names, though (the program that contains the import will yield name `foo` if `who_imports(bar)` is called).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: +1: Clean way of answering the question.  The `who_imports()` function could be optimized, though.  For instance, many `sys.modules.values()` are `None` and could be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to install an import hook that tracks all imports.  See PEP 302 and http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/importlib.html.  However, as the comments above point out, there is probably a better way to structure your code.